# mysql query with multiple table joins to fetch data excluding a matching condition from one table

Tags: php, mysql, join

Looking for some help on mysql query for joining table to extract the data.

I have two main tables,

1. session_schedule ->  all schedules here
   entries:

   40,

   41,

   42
2. session_booking.  -> all enrollments here with student_id

   40 - me

   40 - my friend

   41 - my friend

   42 - none

When a user enrolls for a schedule from the session_schedule, this gets populated in the session_booking table.  Now I want to fetch all schedules which are not enrolled by me.

Please see the following code.

This should address the following cases:

1. sessions not enrolled by anyone.
2. sessions enrolled by others , but not by me.

Its failing the second case, where its picking up session enrolled by me and others.

I am getting all three entries.. 40, 41, 42.
I should not be getting 40

Please see the following code.

```
 $session_schedule = ORM::factory('sessionschedule')->select(
    'sessionschedule.session_id' ,
    'sessions_booking.session_id' ,
    'sessions_booking.student_id', ) 



 ->join('sessions_booking','LEFT')  
 // this join is to exclude already paid sessions by the user                   
 ->on('sessionschedule.id','=','sessions_booking.session_id') 
 ->where('sessionschedule.session_id', '=', $_POST['id'] )
 ->where_open()
 ->where('sessions_booking.session_id','=',NULL) // for sessions nobody booked                                          
 ->or_where('sessions_booking.student_id','!=',$user->id  )// for sessions booked by others             
 ->where_close()    

 ->group_by('sessionschedule.id')->find_all();
```

Comment: To get better answers, please post the relevant table schemas and the actual SQL query generated by your ORM code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ses.* 
FROM session_schedule ses 
LEFT JOIN session_booking sb ON ses.id=sb.session_id AND sb.student_id='me' 
WHERE sb.session_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: your solution is working well.  Thanks a lot for the quick help.

Comment: Thanks.  The solution is working for me.  Thanks once again.